# Re-enable notify-osd (?) after installing MATE

Tags: unity, mate, notify-osd

I'm on 14.04 LTS and before this I was using Unity. I recently tried installing MATE, but I didn't quite like it and I switched back. However, it looks like MATE changed/broke my OSD, and now some of my notifications aren't working.

They used to look like this:
[notify-osd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50i6l.jpg)

But now they look like this: [some other osd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L8l3.png)

(screen brightness is one of the notifications that doesn't appear anymore, along with volume and maybe some others)

Did MATE switch my OSD to some other system or corrupt it somehow, and is there anything I can do to get it back the way it was? I haven't tried uninstalling anything just yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the package `mate-notification-daemon` and you should be just okay.

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-notification-daemon
```

Comment: Sorry reviewers, the answer cannot be longer :D